# Не могу сохранить пару связанных объектов в БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь сделать программу для работы с БД с помощью EF. Построил модель, сгенерировал контекст, сгенерировал базу на основе модели - все вроде бы хорошо.

Пытаюсь сохранить в базу пару связанных объектов - и получаю ошибку:

```
InnerException  {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table
             'vkr.dbo.ClientPhoneSet'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\n
The statement has been terminated."}
System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

И действительно - трассировка БД подтверждает сообщение:
[image: скрин из SQL SERVER Profiler]

Но я никак не могу найти причины подобного несоответсвия, ведь сохраняемые объекты имеют поля ID:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вы явно добавляете BoardSet? у вас они связаны, у вас есть навигационное свойство, явное добавление сущности вам не нужно. Это может привести к ошибке добавления.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov простите, не очень понимаю какое действие подразумевается под явным добавлением BoardSet, но попробую угадать пока вы не ответите. ^_^
(я закомментировал db.BoardSet.Add(board), но ошибка осталась той же)

Comment: да, вы все верно поняли. Покажите пжлста вашу модель

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov https://www.dropbox.com/s/6womncanuyj8dvt/model.png?dl=0
сделал скрины БД и модели EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в следующем:
При создании модели EF у сущностей в ключевом параметре свойство **StoreGeneratedPattern** соответствовало **Identity**.
Изменение свойства на **None** и сохранение модели заставили EF генерировать обычный Insert запрос к базе со всеми 3мя параметрами(включая ID, который не отправлялся в проблемной ситуации).